# Cordova Firebase analytics error with custom URL scheme enable

Tags: cordova, firebase, cordova-plugins, firebase-analytics

I have a cordova app and trying to use Firebase analytics. I install the plugin 'cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics' and it recording . However, I am getting a Deeplink error and the custom url scheme in my does not work .

When I select custom URL with arguments  I get back to my app but arguments are missing.. So, the user does not go back to the specific page

Here is the message I see in iOS

```
Deep Link does not contain valid required params. URL params: {
    downloadUrl = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/9lo39fdcm3dgh/andyadams.docx";
    fileName = "andyadams.docx";
    fileSize = 13993;
    sourceName = dropbox;
}
```

This is one of custom url scheme that I used

```
jobxs://jobs/398056/apply1/upload?downloadUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fdl.dropboxusercontent.com%2F1%2Fview%2F9lo39fdcm3d%2Fandyadams10.docx&fileName=andyadams10.docx&fileSize=13993&sourceName=dropbox
```

As I mention, selecting the link  redirects me to the app but no arguments is sent . If I remove the cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics then the custom URL scheme works

Please let me know how to resolve this issue

Thanks for your help

Comment: Analytics automatically looks for the utm_* params in the deep link so it tells you that there are no params in the link to report any campaign events. What do you mean by "no arguments is sent"? Does it mean that your app still opens with the link, but somehow you don't see the params anymore? Have you tried setting FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled=NO in the Info.plist? Does it work after using that flag? Also, are you using Analytics only or are there other SDKs? Thanks